# Simple Hierarchical Select - Expose Filter - All term

Tags: drupal, view, hierarchy, drupal-exposed-filter

I have a content view, with taxonomy as

- State 01

  - City 01
  - City 02
  - City 03

I am using that field as expose filter using shs. It shows the result when I select some city i-e term-id, but when in select field there is -Any- selected, it shows nothing. In that case ideally it should be showing all node with all terms.

It shows result when url is 
sitename.com/?field_computer_state_target_id=42

But donot output when url is...

sitename.com/?field_computer_state_target_id=all

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I am able to do it myself using some custom code.

```
function glue_custom_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
//dsm($view);
//dsm($query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['value']);
  if ($view->name == 'list_computer_all' && $view->current_display == 'page_1' && $query->where[1]['conditions'][2]['value'] == 'All') {
    unset($query->where[1]['conditions'][2]);
  }
}
```